# Why is my react-lightbox not going full screen in next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm using next.js and I was hoping to see my gallery collection like this [image: like this] on click of one of my images which is not happening. Actually, it's like I have just used a normal component, because literally nothing is happening when I click one of my images. Please help.

```js
// this  is my app component

import SimpleReactLightbox from 'simple-react-lightbox'

const MyApp = ()=>{
  return(
    <SimpleReactLightbox>
     <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SimpleReactLightbox>
  )
}

// this is my collection

import { CollectionStyledTypography } from './styles/collectionStyledComponents'
import { SRLWrapper } from 'simple-react-lightbox'
import Image from 'next/image'

const Collection = ({ imagesList = [] }) => {
  return (
    <SRLWrapper>
      <div style={{ margin: '50px' }}>
        {imagesList.map((image, index) => (
          <CollectionStyledTypography component="div" key={index}>
            <Image src={image.src} alt={image.alt} layout="fill" />
          </CollectionStyledTypography>
        ))}
      </div>
    </SRLWrapper>
  )
}
export default Collection
```

Answer (score 1):

SRL is no longer being developed, and it won't work in React 18. You will have to downgrade to 17 to make it work. I am facing the same problem, nothing happens when i click on an image.